# Script or workflow to modify find and replace backslashes in clipboard

Tags: applescript, automator, copy-paste

I need to do a lot of copying filepaths written by people using a PC (which uses backslashes) to a Mac (which uses forward slashes), and I'm tired of manually switching them every time.  I have to copy the filepath from our shared web browser, paste it into my file browser, and then go in and manually remove the backslash and replace it with a forward slash.

That last part is really what's killing me since basically every filepath I copy has several backslashes in it that I want to paste! What I want is something that will modify the contents of my clipboard so I can just paste it into my Mac file browser without having to manually replace the slashes every time.

In short, I want any "\" in my clipboard to change to a "/" before I paste it. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Using an Automator Service and AppleScript *code*, here are two examples of how you can change *backslashes* to *slashes* in a *string*.

The first one takes the *selected text* passed to the Automator Service, makes the replacements and sets the *output* to the Clipboard. Which from there you can manually paste wherever you desire that can accept pasted text.

The second one takes the *selected text* passed to the Automator Service, makes the replacements and then replaces the *selected text* passed with the *modified text* in place, that is providing the source *selected text* is editable.

There is a slight *code* difference between the two, in the `on run` *subroutine* and a single setting difference between the *services*. Both require first selecting a *text string* and then either a *right-click* to select the *service* from the Context menu or accessing the *service* from the Application_Name > Services > menu. The `on replaceText(find, replace, textString)` *subroutine* is the same in both examples.

**AppleScript *code* for the Clipboard method *service*:**

```
on run {input}
    set the clipboard to replaceText("\\", "/", input as string)
end run

on replaceText(find, replace, textString)
    set prevTIDs to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to find
    set textString to text items of textString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to replace
    set textString to "" & textString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to prevTIDs
    return textString
end replaceText
```

---

**AppleScript *code* for the replace selected text method *service*:**

```
on run {input}
    set input to replaceText("\\", "/", input as string)
    return input
end run

on replaceText(find, replace, textString)
    set prevTIDs to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to find
    set textString to text items of textString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to replace
    set textString to "" & textString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to prevTIDs
    return textString
end replaceText
```

---

**To use the AppleScript *code* in an Automator Service:**

- In **Automator**, create a new **Service** with **Service receives selected text in any application** and **Input is entire selection**, then either leaving unchecked the **[] Output replaces selected text** check box for the clipboard service (AppleScript *code* for the Clipboard method *service*:) or checking the **[√] Output replaces selected text** check box for the for the *replace selected* text service (AppleScript *code* for the replace selected text method *service*:)
- Add a **Run AppleScript** *action* to it and delete the *default code*.
- Copy and paste whichever *code* for the method you choose to use.
- Save the **Service** with an appropriate name, e.g., **Replace backslashes with slashes on Clipboard** for the first one and or **Replace backslashes with slashes in selected text** for the second one. Or of course whatever you prefer.

Now select some text that has *backslashes* in it and then select the *service's* name from the Services Context menu (right-click) or the Application_Name > Services > menu.

If using the Clipboard method, then paste the now *modified selected text* wherever you want or if using the *replace selected text* method, it's already replaced having selected that Service.

Answer (score -1):

1. Keep the Windows quoted path entries into a plain text, name it to paths.txt, such as

   ```
    "C:\Program Files\xyz"
    "C:\Windows\System32"
   ```
2. Then do it in Terminal:

   ```
   cat paths.txt | sed -e 's#\\#\/#g' > converted.txt
   ```
3. The result such as

   ```
   "C:/Program Files/xyz"
   "C:/Windows/System32"
   ```

   if you want to get posix paths, try

   ```
   cat paths.txt | sed -e 's#^\"\([a-zA-Z]\):#\"\/\1#' -e 's#\\#\/#g' > converted.txt
   ```

   the converted result will be:

   ```
   "/C/Program Files/xyz"
   "/C/Windows/System32"
   ```